# Diagonal gradient in css

Tags: css

Most of the gradients I've seen are either vertical or horizontal. Is it possible to have a diagonal gradient using css? I would like to have a gradient that starts out dark in one corner and becomes lighter in the opposite corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jrc72/show

Answer (score 2):

Yes. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ has option to pick diagonal, see orientation.

Answer (score 1):

See this demo http://jsfiddle.net/FQSdb/

and also check out `http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/` for various orientation options